# React - ...requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update a big project from React 17 to 18.
Upon `npm i` I get:

```
npm WARN @reach/dialog@0.16.2 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/dialog@0.16.2 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.6.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/popover@0.16.2 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/popover@0.16.2 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN google-map-react@2.1.10 requires a peer of react@^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN google-map-react@2.1.10 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/listbox@0.16.2 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/listbox@0.16.2 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-autocomplete@1.8.1 requires a peer of react@^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-autocomplete@1.8.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-bootstrap-table-next@4.0.3 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-bootstrap-table-next@4.0.3 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-burger-menu@3.0.6 requires a peer of react@>=0.14.0 <18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-burger-menu@3.0.6 requires a peer of react-dom@>=0.14.0 <18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-credit-cards@0.8.3 requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-custom-scrollbars@4.2.1 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-custom-scrollbars@4.2.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-datepicker@3.8.0 requires a peer of react@^16.9.0 || ^17 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-datepicker@3.8.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.9.0 || ^17 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-dropdown@1.10.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-dropdown@1.10.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-device-detect@1.17.0 requires a peer of react@>= 0.14.0 < 18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-device-detect@1.17.0 requires a peer of react-dom@>= 0.14.0 < 18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-floating-input@2.1.10 requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-floating-input@2.1.10 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-google-maps@9.4.5 requires a peer of @types/googlemaps@^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-google-maps@9.4.5 requires a peer of @types/markerclustererplus@^2.1.29 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-google-maps@9.4.5 requires a peer of @types/react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-google-maps@9.4.5 requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-google-maps@9.4.5 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-loading-skeleton@2.2.0 requires a peer of react@^15.6.1 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-hook-form@6.15.8 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || ^17 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-select@3.2.0 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-select@3.2.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-share@4.4.0 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 || ^17 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-scripts@4.0.3 requires a peer of typescript@^3.2.1 || ^4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-slidedown@2.4.7 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 || 17 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-slidedown@2.4.7 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.3.0 || 17 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-spinners@0.9.0 requires a peer of react@^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-spinners@0.9.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-switch@5.0.1 requires a peer of react@^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-switch@5.0.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-twitter-widgets@1.10.0 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || ^17 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-waypoint@9.0.3 requires a peer of react@^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN redux-form@8.3.8 requires a peer of react@^16.4.2 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN redux-form@8.3.8 requires a peer of immutable@^3.8.2 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/portal@0.16.2 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/portal@0.16.2 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/utils@0.16.0 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/utils@0.16.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/auto-id@0.16.0 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/auto-id@0.16.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/machine@0.16.0 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/machine@0.16.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/descendants@0.16.1 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/descendants@0.16.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/rect@0.16.0 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @reach/rect@0.16.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.0 || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-popper@1.3.11 requires a peer of react@0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-onclickoutside@6.12.1 requires a peer of react@^15.5.x || ^16.x || ^17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-onclickoutside@6.12.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.5.x || ^16.x || ^17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN recompose@0.26.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-side-effect@2.1.1 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.4.3 requires a peer of type-fest@^0.13.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.4.3 requires a peer of webpack-hot-middleware@2.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.4.3 requires a peer of webpack-plugin-serve@0.x || 1.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@10.2.1 requires a peer of fibers@>= 3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@10.2.1 requires a peer of sass@^1.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.16.7 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN jest-config@26.6.3 requires a peer of ts-node@>=9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN jsdom@16.7.0 requires a peer of canvas@^2.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@7.5.7 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@7.5.7 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-input-autosize@3.0.0 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Here it the dependencies list:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@mdi/font": "^5.8.55",
        "@reach/dialog": "^0.16.2",
        "@reach/listbox": "^0.16.2",
        "@reach/popover": "^0.16.2",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "downshift": "^6.0.10",
        "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
        "google-map-react": "^2.1.9",
        "immer": "^8.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "pretty-checkbox": "^3.0.3",
        "qs": "^6.9.4",
        "ramda": "^0.27.1",
        "react": "^18.1.0",
        "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
        "react-autocomplete": "^1.8.1",
        "react-autosuggest": "^10.0.4",
        "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^4.0.3",
        "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^5.1.4",
        "react-burger-menu": "^3.0.2",
        "react-content-loader": "^5.1.4",
        "react-cookie": "^4.0.3",
        "react-credit-cards": "^0.8.3",
        "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
        "react-datepicker": "^3.3.0",
        "react-device-detect": "^1.17.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
        "react-dropdown": "^1.9.0",
        "react-floating-input": "^2.1.10",
        "react-geocode": "^0.2.2",
        "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-hook-form": "^6.15.5",
        "react-loading-skeleton": "^2.2.0",
        "react-numeric-input": "^2.2.3",
        "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.3.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
        "react-responsive": "^9.0.0-beta.6",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
        "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
        "react-select": "^3.1.1",
        "react-share": "^4.3.1",
        "react-slidedown": "^2.4.5",
        "react-spinners": "^0.9.0",
        "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
        "react-swipe": "^6.0.4",
        "react-switch": "^5.0.1",
        "react-toastify": "^6.2.0",
        "react-twitter-widgets": "^1.9.5",
        "react-waypoint": "^9.0.3",
        "reactstrap": "^8.8.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-form": "^8.3.7",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "search-insights": "^2.2.1",
        "swipe-js-iso": "^2.1.5",
        "tiny-slider": "^2.9.4"
    },
```

I have tried to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock`, however the same.
I made a research, but I could find only similar problem when installing some dependencies. However in my case it happens when updating `react` `react-dom` and        `react-router-dom`.

Did anyone spot a similar issue while updating react and knows/can suggest how to fix those warnings?

Thank you